# Persistence Issue for JPA 2.0 on Weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic11g

We were trying to deploy an Application on Weblogic and are getting the below error while Activating Changes. I have done the necessary setup for activating JPA 2.0. If you need further details do let me know and I will share the same. Has anyone faced this before??

```
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
 weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
         at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:633)
         at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
         at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
         at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
         at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
         Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
 Caused By: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
 weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
         at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:633)
         at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
         at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
         at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
         at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
         Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

The weblogic version I can see on the console is as below

WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0.4 PSU Patch for BUG16083651 Thu Mar 28 15:24:29 IST 2013 WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0 Tue Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1441050

Comment: Maybe it would be more useful to show the code that is causing this problem

Comment: what are your dependencies?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am not privy to such information since I am not the developer. All I know is the same WAR file works with 10.3.6(11g) and is not working with this one.

Comment: @Karim Can you tell me where exactly I could look for them?

Comment: sometimes this erreur is generated if you don't have Hibernate-jpa dependencie

Comment: Downgrading to Weblogic 10.3.6.0 resolved the issue. I believe there was some issue with the patch or may be the patch was not installed correctly. Will post here once I know more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a code compatibility problem between the Development and Weblogic version. Downgrading the WebLogic version to 10.3.6.0 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

id you're using maven try to add these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can you post your pom.xml, and are you using any custum validation?